# Who attacked young Sarah Connor?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-genisys

In *Terminator: Genisys*, a T-800 is sent back to when Sarah Connor was a child. In the film, we learn that this was

> because someone attacked her as a child, killing her parents. The T-800 saved her and then

trained her and provided her with information on the future. This incident was not fully explained in the film. Who attacked her as a child?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In an interview with the film's writers and director, [io9](http://io9.com/your-burning-questions-about-the-plot-of-terminator-gen-1715234003) revealed:

> In 1973, when the young Terminator arrives to protect Sarah, she’s just witnessed the death of her parents. The movie mentions “liquid metal” in the scene but the writers confirmed it was the same T-1000, played by Byung-hun Lee, seen later in the movie who was there. “So when she kills that thing in the acid, she’s killing the thing that killed her parents,” said Kalogridis.

Comment: To further add, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_Genisys#Sequels) _Genisys_ is the first of a planned trilogy. I'd be surprised if this isn't a major plotline in a future film.

Comment: So the liquid T-1000 was around since 1973 and did - nothing until 1984? And why didn't Pops and Sarah kill him with acid earlier, but 1984 on the same day when they kill the T-800? It does not seem to me that they both were constantly fleeing from the T-1000 until 1984. But why didn't the T-1000 chase them?